# How to write CASE statement in SQL Server for the logic below?

Tags: sql-server, case

I have my SQL query like this:

```
With Net as 
(
    Select 
        C.region, C.Project_number, C.Country_Name, C.currency_rate, 
        C.snapshot_date, C.H12_LC, C.F12_LC, C.Sales_LC, C.Net_NCC_Cost
    From 
        (
           .......
        )    
)
select 
    region,
    Project_number,
    Country_Name,
    currency_rate,
    snapshot_date,
    isnull(sum(H12_LC), 0) H12_LC,
    isnull(sum(F12_LC), 0) F12_LC,
    isnull(sum(Sales_LC), 0) Sales_LC,
    Net_NCC_Cost
from 
    Net 
group by 
    Net.region, Net.project_number, Net.Country_Name,
```

How and where should I include the case statement for my logic:

```
Total_NCC = [Net_NCC_Cost])+ (IF( (H12 - F12) > 0, -(H12 - F12)*1000000, (-H12 + F12)*1000000)))
```

Thanks

Bob

Comment: what is the purpose of that statement ?

Comment: I need to include that logic in my sql for BI reporting. I need to build a Line chart based on that logic. Total_NCC vs Snapshot_date

Comment: so you want this as part of the result ? then just add to the last `SELECT` clause

Comment: `IIF` is valid SQL syntax (from 2012 onwards) so you don't need a case expression, but rewriting that as a case expression is pretty simple too.

Comment: makes sense. I got it now, thank you @ZLK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case `expressions` are just some words implementing boolean logic, i.e. similar to use of `if`, but with words.

```
SELECT
    region
  , Project_number
  , Country_Name
  , currency_rate
  , snapshot_date
  , ISNULL(SUM(H12_LC), 0)   h12_lc
  , ISNULL(SUM(F12_LC), 0)   f12_lc
  , ISNULL(SUM(Sales_LC), 0) sales_lc
  , Net_NCC_Cost
  , [Net_NCC_Cost] 
    + CASE
          WHEN (H12 - F12) > 0 THEN -(H12 - F12) * 1000000
          ELSE (-H12 + F12) * 1000000
      END AS Total_NCC
FROM yourtable
```

ps: an `expression` evaluates to a single value, a `statement` is something much more complex